# Как убрать у изображения надписи "открыть изображение в новой вкладке" и т.п.?

Tags: html, изображения

У меня есть логотип "VK", при нажатии на который меня перекидывает на мою страничку.

```
<a href="https://vk.com/my_vk_page" target="_blank"><img src="images/vk-logo.png"></a>
```

Но проблема в том, что при нажатии правой кнопкой мыши по изображению логотипа этой  соц.сети, выскакивают надписи, связанные с тем, что это картинка. Например на других сайтах это выглядит так, будто это просто ссылка. Нет надписей, содержащих информацию о том, что это картинка.

---

**Вопрос**: как убрать эти надписи или представить картинку как обычную ссылку?

Answer (score 1):

Есть такое правильно `pointer-events: none;` которое даёт возможность отключить таргет (взаимодействие) с элементом.
В вашем случае, это свойство, нужно применить к картинке.

```
a > img {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```css
a {
  background: black;
  padding: 5px;
}

a > img {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://vk.com/images/svg_icons/ic_head_logo.svg">
</a>
```

Подробнее о [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.vk{background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/21/VK.com-logo.svg/500px-VK.com-logo.svg.png) no-repeat;background-size:cover;width:50px;height:50px;overflow:hidden;border:none;cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<input class="vk" type="button" value="" 
onclick="location.href = 'https://vk.com'"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделать это через css background

Вот так вот:

```css
a.vk {
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/21/VK.com-logo.svg/1200px-VK.com-logo.svg.png) no-repeat top center;
  background-size: 35px 35px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
}
a.vk:hover {
 opacity: 0.8
}
```

```html
<a href="https://vk.com/my_vk_page" class="vk"></a>
```